# How can I automatically name columns in rbind?

Tags: r, rbind

I often rbind vectors with the same variables:

```
v1 = 1
v2 = 2
rbind(c(v1, v2), c(v1, v2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
```

I know I can explicitly name the vector columns, but it's rather tedious and redundant when you have many variables:

```
rbind(c(v1 = v1, v2 = v2), c(v1= v1, v2 = v2))
     v1 v1
[1,]  1  2
[2,]  1  2
```

How can I instruct rbind() to use the variable names to name each column?

Comment: Why make it hard on yourself? Just add another line of code that adds the names quite  easily.  `colnames(x) <- ...`

Comment: Just use `data.frame()` instead of `c()`. (Although I think there's a typo in your second example; the column names aren't consistent across the things you are binding.)

Comment: @RichardScriven I could, but imagine if you have dozens of variables in the results vector. Then you have to type the full list in the final matrix or date frame, even though the information is already available in the vectors.

Comment: @joran I like your solution. Sounds like you really can't do the same with vectors?

Comment: @josilber might disagree with your pessimism. ;)

Comment: @RobertKubrick Use `rbind(cbind(v1, v2), cbind(v1, v2))` to get a column auto-labeled matrix.

Comment: @A.Webb Nice trick! You should post an answer.

Comment: It is `c` that needs to account for variable names. So, you could build your own concatenation function to achieve your goal functionally. I.e. `c2 = function(...) { args = as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]; setNames(c(...), sapply(args, deparse)) }`. And, then, `rbind(c2(v1, v2), c2(v1, v2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `rbind` and `mget`:

```
v1 <- 1
v2 <- 2

rbind(mget(c("v1", "v2")), mget(c("v1", "v2")))
```

`mget` will search the environment for variables with the given names. Most importantly, the result is a named `list` object.

However, I think a cleaner solution is to just make a `data.frame`, as suggested above:

```
rbind(data.frame(v1, v2), data.frame(v1, v2))
```

Comment: A similar idea with `mget` was posted by me and deleted as the OP is not looking for it.

Comment: Nothing.  It was just that the other solution is the preferred one as it makes use of the `rbind`'s properties that you need to name it only once. :-)

Comment: The other solution isn't automatic... oh well!

Comment: I deleted my solution `new <- mget(ls(pattern='^v\\d+'));t(replicate(2, new))` (for this example)

Comment: mget and data.frame() are both fine.

Comment: @RobertKubrick  You didn't mention about this while I posted the solution though..

Answer (score 5):

You only need to name the elements in the first vector passed to `rbind`:

```
v1 <- 1
v2 <- 2
rbind(c(v1=v1, v2=v2), c(v1, v2), c(4, 5))
#      v1 v2
# [1,]  1  2
# [2,]  1  2
# [3,]  4  5
```

I'm assuming the example you provide was simplified and you're not planning on repeating the same row many times; if so, there are easier ways than typing the row a lot of times (e.g. using `replicate` or `rep`).

Comment: Good to know, but in my case I can't tell which vector will be the first to rbind. I use by() to split a data frame and calculate aggregate data for each subset. In other cases I have mclapply() that runs in parallel on each list element and I rbind the results.